# How do you detect a key word in a sentence no matter the tense, form in python?

Tags: python, string, text, nlp, spacy

I am trying to use spaCy in Python to detect the word "grief" no matter the form, whether it is "I am grieving", "going through grief.""I grieved over __", if it's in all caps, etc. I am pretty new to python so I don't know lemmatization that well, but is there some simple if statements that could solve it using spaCy?

```
grief = str(input(("What is currently on your mind? ")))
doc = nlp(grief)
if [t.grief for t in doc if t.lemma_ == "grie"]:
    grief1(sad_value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make use of the `spaCy` lemmatiser, you need to check for two lemmas: "grief" and "grieve". However, this doesn't catch all cases as one might initially expect (see below).

In general, one should not always assume that the `spaCy` lemma output will be lowercase, nor assume that random capitalisation of letters in a given input word does not influence the result. For example,

- "Grief is what I feel" outputs "Grief" for the lemma instead of "grief".
- "I am gRieviNG" outputs "grieving" instead of the expected (correct) lemma "grieve" (which is what one gets if "I am grieving" is capitalised normally).

[This Medium article](https://medium.com/besedo-engineering/spacys-lemmatizer-lowercase-limitations-1155c1787158) by Jade Moillic highlights the lowercase limitations of the `spaCy` lemmatiser quite well.

To handle these situations, one can force the lemma output to be lowercase, and then also add "grieving" as a possible lemma to check. Alternatively, [Stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) via the `SnowballStemmer` implementation provides a robust option. Solutions are as follows.

### spaCy Lemmatiser-based Solution

```py
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm', exclude=["ner"])
grief = str(input(("What is currently on your mind? ")))
# Input: "I am grieving"
doc = nlp(grief)
for t in doc:
    lem = t.lemma_.lower()
    if lem == "grief" or lem == "grieve" or lem == "grieving":
        print("Found {}".format(lem))
# Output: "Found grieve"
```

### Examples for testing with spaCy Lemmatiser

```py
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm', exclude=["ner"])
texts = ["Grief is what I feel", "Grieving is not something I'm used to", "I am grieving", "Going through grief", "I will grieve", "I grieved", "He grieves", "I am gRieviNG"]
docs = list(nlp.pipe(texts))
for doc in docs:
    print(doc.text)
    for t in doc:
        lem = t.lemma_.lower()
        if lem == "grief" or lem == "grieve" or lem == "grieving":
            print("\t-> Found {}".format(lem))

# Output
# Grief is what I feel
#         -> Found grief
# Grieving is not something I'm used to
#         -> Found grieve
# I am grieving
#         -> Found grieve
# Going through grief
#         -> Found grief
# I will grieve
#         -> Found grieve
# I grieved
#         -> Found grieve
# He grieves
#         -> Found grieve
# I am gRieviNG
#         -> Found grieving
```

### Stemming-based Solution

```py
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

stemmer = SnowballStemmer(language='english')
grief = str(input(("What is currently on your mind? ")))
for token in word_tokenize(grief):
    stem = stemmer.stem(token)
    if stem == 'grief' or stem == 'griev':
        print("Found {}".format(stem))
```

Comment: Just adding that if "Grief" is used as the first word in a sentence, with an initial capital letter, `t.lemma_` will keep the capital letter and the check would fail. The solution consists in just comparing `t.lemma_.lower()` to the forms you are searching for.

Comment: @NicolaFanelli Thank you, good pickup---I'll update the answer accordingly. The alternative stemming solution I posted appears to be more robust to varied capitalisation. It seems you've highlighted a general issue with making comparisons to `spaCy`-generated lemmas when assuming lower case output. Although spaCy often formats the strings to lower case, it doesn't always produce the output one would expect. This [article](https://medium.com/besedo-engineering/spacys-lemmatizer-lowercase-limitations-1155c1787158) highlights the limitations well.